# I need to calculate Stage-Specific Time from Cumulative Time Data using New Relic

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am working with a system that involves multiple processors and several stages. There are five processors and seven stages in total. I use New Relic to track two types of data:

The exact time duration each entity spends within a processor.
The cumulative time each entity spends within a stage, where the time for a stage includes the time spent in all previous stages.
My objective is to measure the stagnation time for each entity, defined as the duration an entity stays within a stage but is waiting to be processed by the processor. To achieve this, I first need to isolate the actual time spent specifically within each stage.
For example, how can I accurately extract the duration an entity spent specifically in stage 3, by subtracting the time from stages 1 and 2, using New Relic data?
Once I have the isolated time for each stage, I then need to subtract the time each entity spent in the processor (also tracked) to compute the stagnation time. Could you guide me on how to carry out these calculations with New Relic